# iMacros Twitter Like

Tags: twitter, bots, imacros

Here is the bot for the auto liker:

```
TAB T=1
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:ProfileTweet-actionButton<SP>js-actionButton<SP>js-actionFavorite”
WAIT SECONDS=1
```

And here is the error:

> RuntimeError: element BUTTON specified by
>   CLASS:ProfileTweet-actionButtonjs-actionButtonjs-actionFavorite”
>   was not found, line: 2

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify more details about the button, the below code seems to work fine.

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TYPE:button&&DATA-MODAL:ProfileTweet-retweet&&CLASS:ProfileTweet-actionButton<SP><SP>js-actionButton<SP>js-actionRetweet
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=24 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Close
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

The selector is from this [`forum link`](https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=26420).